# Writing Powershell Error messages to SSIS

Tags: powershell, ssis

I have an SSIS execute process task where I am calling a PowerShell script. I found that I can get the process task to fail if the PowerShell script fails by trapping the errors like this:

```powershell
trap {
  $err = $_.Exception
  while ( $err.InnerException )
  {
    $err = $err.InnerException
    Write-Host $err.Message
  };
  exit 1
}
```

I would like to get the error messages to return to SSIS, but I can't seem to get it to work. It just returns the following:

> The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Any help is appreciated.

Full Code:

```powershell
Param(
 [String]$excelPath,
 [String]$serverName,
 [String]$databaseName,
 [String]$tableName
 )

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO.SqlDataType') | Out-Null

Trap {
  $err = $_.Exception
  while ( $err.InnerException )
    {
    $err = $err.InnerException
    Write-Host $err.Message
    };
    exit 1
  }

$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$excel.visible = $False 
$excel.displayalerts=$False 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath) 
$workSheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1).name 
$workbook.Close()
$excel.quit() 
$excel = $null

$query = "select * from [$workSheet`$]";

$connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$excelPath`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES`";"

# Instantiate some objects which will be needed
$serverSMO = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($serverName)
$db = $serverSMO.Databases[$databaseName];

$newTable = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table ;
$newTable.Parent = $db;
$newTable.Name = $tableName ;

$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectionString)
$conn.open()


$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($query,$conn) 
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd) 
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable 

$dataAdapter.fill($dataTable)
$conn.close()

# Drop the table if it exists
if($db.Tables.Contains($tableName).Equals($true))
{
    ($db.Tables[$tableName]).Drop()
}

# Iterate the columns in the DataTable object and add dynamically named columns to the SqlServer Table object.
foreach($col in $dataTable.Columns)
    {
    $sqlDataType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType]::Varchar
    $dataType = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType($sqlDataType);
    $dataType.MaximumLength = 1000;
    $newColumn = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($newTable,$col.ColumnName,$dataType);
    $newColumn.DataType = $dataType;
    $newTable.Columns.Add($newColumn);
}
$newTable.Create();

#bcp data into new table
$connectionString = "Data Source=$serverName;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;"
$bc = New-Object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
$bc.DestinationTableName = "$tableName"
$bc.WriteToServer($dataTable)
```

Comment: I can't set up a test just now so won't make this an answer but have you tried changing the Write-Host to a Write-Error?

Comment: Yes, when I do that the task no longer fails.

Comment: If I leave it at Write-Host I can then put a variable in the StandardOutputVariable of the execute process task. That is populated with the error messages. Seems like an odd way to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. If that's what's returned, then that's the value of **.Exception.InnerException.Message** in the ErrorRecord object thrown by whatever error you're trapping. What kind of output were you expecting, and why? Can you post the code that generates the error you're trapping to make this reproducible?

Comment: I am trying to import an excel file with unknown number of columns into a sql table. I was testing what happened when I couldn't connect to the sql server. I updated the original post with my code.